# NOT WORKING: Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate() does not work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, axios

I am trying to create a (MERN stack) management system that keeps track of vacant rooms in a hotel.

**I am trying to change the roomTypeAOccupiedTotal from 2 to 3.**

From the client side, it sends an axios.put()request as follows:

```
 axios
      .put(`http://localhost:8082/api/myHotel/${branchStatus.id}`, data)
```

this is the server-side code:

```
router.put('/:_id', (req, res) => {

  /*
  req.params looks like this:
  { _id: '63b4d533fabbf31cdb519896' }

  req.body looks like this:
  roomOccupied5F: 3,
  roomOccupied6F: 5,
  roomTypeAOccupiedTotal: 2,
  roomTypeBOccupiedTotal: 8,
  */
  
  let filter = { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params._id) }
  let update = { $set: req.body } 

  MyHotel.findByIdAndUpdate(filter, update, {new: true})
  .then(data => res.json({ msg: 'updated successfully' }))
  .catch(err =>
    res.status(400).json({ error: 'Unable to update the Database' })
  );
```

Below are the GET request and PUT request sent using POSTMAN.
after the message "updated successfully", I sent another GET request to check, but there are no changes to the variable(roomTypeAOccupiedTotal).

Could someone help me with solving this problem? the findByIdAndUpdate() method is working, as its not throwing any errors, but its not updating.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is the filter object. Looking at the docs for findByIdAndUpdate, it expects to receive the id param, not a filter object.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-findByIdAndUpdate

> Parameters:
>
> > id «Object|Number|String» value of _id to query by

Additionally, when you create an objectId out of the request param, you aren't creating a new instance of it, so whatever was passed in would have failed to match anything. My IDE highlights this for me:

[image]

Your fix is likely something like this:

```
const id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params._id)
MyHotel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, {new: true})
```

Comment: I've tried with your recommendation, but unfortunately, it does not update...

Comment: If you chuck a breakpoint down on the line where the find and update is called, does the id value look correct?

edit:

Im also pretty sure the data object in your .then() callback may highlight some extra info, may be worth logging that before returning your response. Or just return the data object in the response while figuring out what's wrong with it?

Comment: `findByIdAndUpdate` will implicitly cast the first argument to objectId, so it is not necessary to convert it first.

Comment: I tried using findById() with the same id as a parameter, and it returns correctly.

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert `id`, and no need to use the update operator(i.e. `$set`).

try this:

```js
MyHotel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params._id, req.body, { new: true }, (err, hotel) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(hotel);
    }
});
```